# Product of 2 Gaussian Distributions with Different Variables

Tags: normal-distribution

Sorry, I asked the original question improperly so I am rephrasing it.

What is the mean and covariance of the distribution, $f_{PA}(PA) \cdot f_{Y|X,PA}(Y)$ where $f_{PA}$ and $f_{Y|X,PA}$ are both gaussian distributions?  (The distribution over $X,Y,PA$ is Gaussian.)  $Y,PA$ are vectors.

Comment: Hint: Independent random variables are uncorrelated. So the _covariance_ matrix of $Z$ has a block structure: $$\Sigma_Z = \begin{bmatrix}\Sigma_X & \mathbf 0\\\mathbf 0 & \Sigma_Y\end{bmatrix}$$ where $\Sigma_X$ and $\Sigma_Y$ are the covariance matrices of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Hmm.  I see that X and Y are independent because the P(X, Y) = P(X)P(Y) in the way I phrased this question.  However, X and Y should not necessarily be independent...  I must be interpreting my results incorrectly.  I have a distribution over the variables in Z that equals N(X; 0; V_X)*N(Y; mu_Y; V_Y) where XUY = Z.  Does this alone require that X and Y are independent?  Does it make sense to say N(X; 0; V_X) is not marginal distribution of Z over X?  Rather, it is a different distribution over the variables in X?